# Get unique values FIRST from sheet, then filter based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to see if any of you know of a formula that replicates removing duplicates/counting only the unique values from a list and then counting the unique values based on multiple criteria.

I've already tried formula's like:

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(criteria,MATCH(values,values,0)),ROW(values)-ROW(values.firstcell)+1)>0))}
```

but it doesn't get what I want.

For instance, say I have this table:

```
DATE    STATUS  ACCOUNT #
3-Dec-15    ONGOING 1391937
25-May-17   ON HOLD 1391937
13-May-17   ON HOLD 1391937
14-Sep-17   ONGOING 2490936
25-May-16   ONGOING 1285792
26-Jul-16   ON HOLD 1285792
21-May-17   ON HOLD 1285792
23-Feb-17   ON HOLD 1512450
26-May-17   ONGOING 2604610
23-Sep-17   ON HOLD 1122902
```

and I wanted to get the number of unique account numbers when the date is within the year 2017 and the status is 'ON HOLD'. If I used this formula

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((B2:B11 = "ON HOLD")*(A2:A11 >= DATE(2017,1,1)),MATCH(C2:C11,C2:C11,0)),ROW(C2:C11)-ROW(C2)+1)>0))}
```

I would get '4', which is like filtering first for the two criteria and then counting the unique values.

But what I really need to get is '2', as if you first removed the ACCOUNT # duplicates and then filtered for the other two criteria.

Is this something that's possible? Maybe I'm just missing something, but hopefully you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The account numbers that should be left are 1512450 and 1122902 for accounts within 2017 and are ON HOLD.

Comment: Please give the accountnumbers that should be counted in the endresult.

Comment: When you first remove the duplicates and then filter on the criteria "ON HOLD" and year 2017, the count of the result will not be stable. It depends on what rows are removed. When you remove row 1 & 2, account# 1391937 will be counted in the end result (row 3). When you remove row 2 & 3, account# 1391937 will not be counted in the end result, because it is not "ON HOLD" (and not in 2017).

Comment: So you're saying that the rows that could be deleted are variable? So I could end up with different results depending on how the duplicates are removed, right?

Comment: Yep. That's what i mean.

Comment: Alright well I guess that answers my question then, I can't be relying on unstable information after all. Thanks for helping me out, much appreciated :)

Comment: Or you could redefine your criteria. Should account# 1391937 be in your result set (counted)? Why, or why not?

Answer (score 0):

A multi-celled Array formula can give you the results you desire.With "Date","Status" and "Account #" assumed to be in cells A1, B1 and C1 respectively, select the cell range D2:D100 and enter =RIGHT(TRIM(A$2:A$100),2)="17" using the combination Ctrl+Shift+Enter in the formula bar.In selected range E2:E100 enter =(TRIM(B$2:B$100)="ON HOLD") using Ctrl+Shift+Enter in the formula bar.In F2:F100 enter =IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C$100,C$2:C$100)=1,C$2:C$100,"") and in G2 enter =IF(D2*E2=0,"",F2), press Enter and copy down.It is Column G that holds your results.

To get a count of unique accounts that qualify, put this Array formula in G1: =COUNT((G2:G100)*1) using Ctrl+Shift+Enter. My cell ranges in the formulas were purely arbitrary.The actual selected ranges should match the ranges of your data.

Comment: @ ThatOneCanadian : As an updated and streamlined answer to my original post, put the following non-array formula in D2 and copy down as needed : =IF(((COUNTIF(C$2:C$11,C2)=1)*(TRIM(B2)="ON HOLD")*(RIGHT(TRIM(A2),2)="17"))>0,C2,""). The unique qualifying count formula can be moved to cell D1.

Comment: @ ThatOneCanadian : If you would prefer the results to be continuously adjacent, then you can put this Array formula in D2 and copy down : =IFERROR(SMALL(IF(((COUNTIF(C$2:C$11,C3:C12)=1)*(TRIM(B3:B12)="ON HOLD")*(RIGHT(TRIM(A3:A12),2)="17"))>0,1*(C3:C12),""),ROW()-1),"").